How to generate distinct download buttons in Python Shiny modules
I am working on a Shiny App in Python, and it uses modules to reproduce the same plots/calculations etc on different input data. Plots and data manipulation work as expected, but the content of the download button is being overwritten by the last one called in the app server function.
If I have 5 module calls with a download button each, all 5 download buttons give the same data.
Minimal code:
from shiny import App, module, render, ui


@module.ui
def example_ui():
    return ui.output_ui("download_button")


@module.server
def example_server(
    input,
    output,
    session,
    label,
):
    @render.download(filename="{}.csv".format(label))
    def download_data():
        yield label

    @output
    @render.ui
    def download_button():
        return (ui.download_button("download_data", "Download {}".format(label)),)


app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    example_ui("foo"),
    example_ui("bar"),
)


def server(input, output, session):
    example_server("foo", "foo")
    example_server("bar", "bar")


app = App(app_ui, server)


I expect this code to generate buttons that download a foo.csv and bar.csv respectively, but both buttons cause a bar.csv to download. Reversing the order of the two lines in the server() def causes both buttons to return foo.csv.
My best understanding is that the cause is the way download buttons are defined, with the download_data() function being overwritten by the second call before the first UI button element is generated, but I haven't been able to figure out any way to resolve this within the modules.

You were correct with your diagnosis. This should work for you.
from shiny import App, module, render, ui


@module.ui
def example_ui():
    return ui.output_ui("download_button")


@module.server
def example_server(
    input,
    output,
    session,
    label,
):
    @output(id = label) ## Gave each output a unique ID
    @render.download(filename="{}.csv".format(label))
    def irrelevant_now(): 
        yield label

    @output
    @render.ui
    def download_button(): 
        return (ui.download_button(label, "Download {}".format(label)),)


app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    example_ui("foo"),
    example_ui("bar"),
)


def server(input, output, session):
    example_server("foo", "foo")
    example_server("bar", "bar")


app = App(app_ui, server)

Even though every output_ui referenced "download_button", they were understood to be different. But the render.download sections were all interpreted to be identical and overwrote each other, leaving only the final version instead of distinct identities.
The fix comes from the example for "download4". Give each button a unique ID (your label) and reference that ID in the @output decorator for your render.download block.
It seems that the ID is what keeps the functions independent, and the function name is irrelevant.
BTW it was only giving me ".htm" files. Hopefully, yours is properly showing ".csv" extensions.
